# fit a image to a dubble table (mailChimp)

Tags: javascript, html-email, mailchimp

I want my picture fill the entire table but I can't make it because it seems I have cell and dubble table. 
Can you help me figure it out what is going on with my code? 
It is on mailChimp but I coded myself because I want a linkable picture and a linkable button. 
So I want my picture covered the entire table enven the contact us button (I already know it isn't center but that's another point I will be able to handle lately).
Thanks in advance for your help.

```html
<table border="0"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-left:0px;"> </td>
<div class="mcnImage">
<a href="https://www.immeractive.com" target="_blank"> <img src="https://www.immeractive.com/wp-content/uploads/Immeractive_MailChimp.jpg" alt="Visualization3D_immeractive" title="Immeractive_ContactUs" height="100%" width="100%" class="emailImage" style="display:block;"style="vertical-align: baseline;"/> </a>
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){.emailImage{ height:auto !important; max-width:400px !important; width: 400px !important;};"vertical-align: baseline </style>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="emailButton" style="border-radius:95px; background-color:#4bb5c6;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" class="emailButtonContent" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:15px;">
      <a href="mailto:info@immeractive.com?subject=Information e-mail" email="" me="" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Open sans; font-size:15px; font-weight:Regular; text-decoration:none;">CONTACT US</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. The first `<table>` contains a `<td>` immediately.
   You must put a `<tr>` between `<table>` and `<td>` (and later close it with `</tr>`).
2. You have a `<div>` directly in the first `<table>`, but that is not allowed; it can only be inside of a `<td>`, or *not* inside of the table. Maybe you accidentally closed the `<td>` that precedes it too soon, or you forgot to add a new `<td>`.
3. The contents of the `<style>` block are syntactically wrong: there are two opening **`{`** braces, but only one closing **`}`** brace, which also seems to have been put too early because strange text follows it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) I'm absolutely not an expert (marketing & comm student) but i want to give a chance to try.
I correct what you told me and is actually better but the picture don't cover the entire table, what should I do?

Comment: Best to try a little more, make it as good as you can, and if still needed then post a new question containing the HTML that you have at that point. Also a **tip**: use the `[Tidy]` button when creating the Stack Overflow code snippet, it will re-format the code before you post it, doing so may reveal problems because the re-formatted code will look "strange" if you left certaom mistakes in your HTML.